# Getting MicrosoftOnlineException when website is hosted in IIS

Tags: powershell, iis, office365

There is a powershell script that gets called from asp.net .
The powershell basically connects to Windows Azure Module.

When I debug the asp.net from VS it gets hosted in IIs-express and the powershell script runs as expected.
But when the website is hosted in IIS, the below exception is being thrown

```
System.Management.Automation.InvalidPowerShellStateException occurred
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.
Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException: You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.BecWebServiceInspector.BeforeSendRequest(Message& request, IClientChannel channel)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableClientRuntime.BeforeSendRequest(ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.PrepareCall(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Boolean oneway, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IProvisioningWebService.GetRoleByName(GetRoleByNameRequest request)
   at ProvisioningWebServiceClient.GetRoleByName(GetRoleByNameRequest request)
System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingException: Cannot bind parameter 'RoleObjectId' to the target. Exception setting "RoleObjectId": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." ---> System.Management.Automation.SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "RoleObjectId": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object )
   at System.Management.Automation.ReflectionParameterBinder.BindParameter(String name, Object value)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.ReflectionParameterBinder.BindParameter(String name, Object value)
   at System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata, ParameterBindingFlags flags)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
   at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)

  Source=ManagementConsoleV2
  StackTrace:
       at ManagementConsoleV2.Structures.Lync_Online.PowershellWrapper.RunPowerShellScript(String userName, String plainPassword, PowerShellScriptType powerShellScriptType) in c:\Dev Team\Sameer\Trunk\Web\ManagementConsoleV2\Structures\Lync Online\PowershellWrapper.cs:line 64
  InnerException:
```

When the application is run in IIS-express, the process runs in 32 bit mode. I have also hosted the application in both 32 bit/64 bit mode threadpool in IIS but getting the same error both time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IIS
Go to **advanced settings** of the application thread pool where your site is set to run in and Set 
**Load user Profile : true**